# How do i store multiple inputs in an array with ionic2/angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic2

I have a dynamic list of user inputs. The user is able to add a destination by clicking "Add Destination" which generates an input field. Once the field is generated, the user enters the destination and clicks a button that should store all of the destinations in an Array. The user should be able to add multiple destinations.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form>
    <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Starting</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let destination of destinations" >
    <ion-label fixed>Destination</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>


  <button  ion-button color="light" icon-right (click)="addDestination()" >
      Add Destination
      <ion-icon name="add" ></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 92%">
    <button ion-button block (click)="store()">Find Path</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public destinations = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }





  addDestination(){
    this.destinations.push(1);
    console.log(this.destinations);
    console.log('hello');
  }

  store(){
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(this.destinations);
  }

}
```

Comment: ngModel will be = destinations[$index]. So each input has holds a value of the array

Comment: is that with angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant in my comment:

```
<div *ngFor="let destination of destinations; let i = index">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="destinations[i]"/>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/mZi1UYI9drNFRwVQsJs5?p=preview

Comment: This has partly worked mate thanks! But the problem now is that whenever I add a destination, all of the input fields are cleared of any input. Is there a way to save the inputs to the fields?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZzU3StsH7p4QNKvtPGTQ?p=preview

Comment: With your solution if you add input in one of the boxes it fills other boxes.

Comment: Check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/GVP5GZfXTQinoV683ssA?p=preview || I replaced your array of strings with an array of objects. Works better in my opinion.

Comment: can you add a viewletters() function that console.logs all the objects in the destinations array

Comment: You can do it. It's the same logic as the add button. Add a button that calls a function that console logs the data. Did this last change (strings => objects) resolved the problem?

Comment: It does resolve the problem, but is there any way to take all of "name" values and place them in an array? I need an array of strings not an array of objects